# Is there a function in C# to check a list sequence with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have two *lists* and need to check whether the **sequence** of items in both the *lists* are same that have `Regex`.

```
For instance I have one list with items {c1, s1?, s2?, s3}.

Valid Sequence:   {c1, s1, s2, s3}, 
                  {c1, s3}.

Invalid Sequence: {c1, c1, s1, s2, s3}, 
                  {c1, s2, s1, s3}, 
                  {c1},
                  {s3, c1}.
```

Comment: No such standard method exist, as far as i know, be prepared to coding it. ;)

Comment: Does *order* matter? I.e. is `{s3, c1}` a valid sequence?

Comment: Yes the order matters. {s3, c1} should be invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that some kind of `delimiter`, say `","` *never appears* within items we can build *regular expression*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  const string delimiter = ",";

  private static string ItemToRegex(string item, int index) {
    string value = item.TrimEnd('+', '*', '?');
    string suffix = item.Substring(value.Length);

    return $"(?:{(index <= 0 ? "" : delimiter)}{Regex.Escape(value)}){suffix}";
  }

  private static Regex ListToRegex(IEnumerable<string> list) {
    string pattern = "^" + string.Concat(list.Select((item, index) => ItemToRegex(item, index))) + "$";

    return new Regex(pattern);
 }
```

Then to test a sequence we should `Join` its items by the `"delimiter"` and use regex:

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>() {
    "c1", "s1?", "s2?", "s3"
 };

 Regex regex = ListToRegex(list);

 List<string> testList = new List<string>() {"c1", "s3"};

 Console.Write(regex.IsMatch(testList.Join(delimiter)));
```

**Demo:**

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>() {
    "c1", "s1?", "s2?", "s3"
  };

  Regex regex = ListToRegex(list);

  List<string>[] tests = new List<string>[] {
    new List<string>() {"c1", "s1", "s2", "s3"},
    new List<string>() {"c1", "s3"},
    new List<string>() {"c1", "c1", "s1", "s2", "s3"},
    new List<string>() {"c1", "s2", "s1", "s3"},
    new List<string>() {"c1" },
    new List<string>() {"s3", "c1" },
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => new {
      valid = regex.IsMatch(string.Join(delimiter, test)) ? "Valid" : "Invalid",
      text = string.Join(", ", test)
    })
    .Select(test => $"{test.valid,-8} :: {test.text}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 Valid    :: c1, s1, s2, s3  
 Valid    :: c1, s3
 Invalid  :: c1, c1, s1, s2, s3
 Invalid  :: c1, s2, s1, s3
 Invalid  :: c1
 Invalid  :: s3, c1
```